# Flutter: Getting all properties of a widget

Tags: flutter, dart, properties, widget

I want to create a new `Widget` that wraps an `IconButton` and overrides its `onPressed` property, but I want that new `Widget` to accept all `IconButton`'s other properties.

In React Native I could just set the `propsTypes` of a component to be another component's `propsTypes`.

Here's an example where I needed it:

```dart
class AudioWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Icon child;

  AudioWidget(this.child); // How do I get all of IconButton's properties?

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: child,
      onPressed: () => play(context), // Some custom function
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm almost sure you cannot get these properties with Dart. And even if you can i'm pretty sure you can't spread these properties to the IconButton. Unfortunately

Comment: You'll have to add the properties you want in your constructor and passed them to your IconButton

Answer (score 1):

You "can" do this by using the constructor in a hacky way

```
class AudioWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Icon child;

  AudioWidget(this.child):mySize=child.size; // In the contructor now we are getting the size and assignin it to OUR size
  final double mySize;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: child,
      onPressed: () {}// Some custom function
    );
  }
}
```

another example with more than one parameter is

```
class AudioWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Icon child;

  AudioWidget(this.child):
  this.mySize=child.size,
  this.myColor= child.color
  ;// How do I get all of IconButton's properties?
  final double mySize;
  final Color myColor;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: child,
      onPressed: () {}// Some custom function
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure I follow, what do you do with `mySize`? If I'm not mistaken, you're suggesting to re-implement the logic that exists inside `IconButton`, which is definitely something I want to avoid.